# porting libjingle to Android issue

Tags: android, stl, android-ndk, libjingle

I found a very strange issue.when I try to invoke connect() in signal1.(sigslot.h).

```
m_connected_slots.push_back(conn);
```

it doesn't work.

For example.

```
std::list<_connection_base1<arg1_type, mt_policy> *>  connections_list_test; 
connections_list_test.push_back(conn);
```

If I create a temp list named connections_list_test.It can work and push_back is correctly.

But the m_connected_slots can't push_back.

Obviously I must be hitting some nonstandard behavior in the STL library i'm using.

Can you guys give some suggest about this issue? or some other android porting experience?

Here is some logs for this:

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0000008c
Stack frame #00  pc 00096f7a  /data/data/com.molo.app/lib/libjingle_jni.so: Routine           insert in /Users/gongchen/Dev/android-ndk-r8/sources/cxx-stl/stlport/stlport/stl/_list.h:427
Stack frame #01  pc 00098ae8  /data/data/com.molo.app/lib/libjingle_jni.so: Routine MoloClient in   /Users/gongchen/Dev/Eclipse_workspace/P2Pdemo/jni/talk/mymolo/moloclient.cc:136
Stack frame #02  pc 00094f54  /data/data/com.molo.app/lib/libjingle_jni.so: Routine    Java_com_molo_app_NativeMethod_doLogin in  /Users/gongchen/Dev/Eclipse_workspace/P2Pdemo/jni/com_molo_app_NativeMethod.cc:215
Stack frame #03  pc 00017d74  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #04  pc 00048f54  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #05  pc 00041b16  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #06  pc 0004e624  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #07  pc 0001cfd4  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #08  pc 000220dc  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #09  pc 00020fd0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #10  pc 0005f430  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #11  pc 0005f656  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #12  pc 00053b4e  /system/lib/libdvm.so
Stack frame #13  pc 00011a7c  /system/lib/libc.so
Stack frame #14  pc 00011640  /system/lib/libc.so
```